# How to get filtered Results in Query using Laravel's Eloquent Clauses - Having, GroupBy?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, eloquent

I've 3 tables. Their structures are as follows:

```
1. Table I - listings

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  
id | name | location_id | is_approved | is_bookable  
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  

2. Table II - programmes (Polymorphic - Many to Many)  
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  
id | listing_id | name | base_price | owner_id | owner_type  
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

3. Table III - timeslots (One to Many with programmes)  
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=  
id | programme_id | start_time | end_time | discount | inventory  
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
```

I want to get those slots (with their - programme & listing) which lies in as follows:

```
start_time => '2015-11-10 00:00:00'  
end_time => '2015-11-10 23:59:59'  
inventory => 'greater than 0'  
owner_id => 'equals 1'  
owner_type => 'equals Activity'  
location_id => 'equals 3'
```

Group them by 'programmes.listing_id' having 'min(price)'

I've made a eloquent query like this: 
[raw code]

```
$query = Timeslot::where('start_time', '>', $start_time)
                            ->where('end_time', '<', $end_time)
                            ->where('inventory', '>', 0)
                            ->whereHas('properties', function($properties_query) use ($timeslot_type) {
                              if(!is_null($timeslot_type)) {
                                $properties_query->where('timeslot_property_id', $timeslot_type);
                              }
                            })
                            ->whereHas('programme', function($programme_query) use ($programme_id, $programme_type, $location_id) {
                              if(!is_null($programme_type) && !is_null($programme_id)) {
                                $programme_query->where('owner_id', $programme_id)
                                                ->where('owner_type', $programme_type);
                              }
                              $programme_query->whereHas('listing', function($listing_query) use ($location_id) {
                                $listing_query->where('is_approved', 1)
                                              ->where('is_bookable', 1)
                                              ->whereHas('location', function($location_query) use ($location_id) {
                                                if(!is_null($location_id)) {
                                                  $location_query->where('id', $location_id);
                                                }
                                              });
                              });
                            })
                            ->join('programmes', 'timeslots.programme_id', '=', 'programmes.id')
                            ->select(['timeslots.*',
                                      DB::raw('(discount/100)*programmes.base_price as discounted_price'),
                                      DB::raw('(programmes.base_price - ((discount/100)*programmes.base_price)) as price')
                                    ])
                            ->with(['programme', 'programme.listing']);

          $query->groupBy('programmes.listing_id')
                ->havingRaw('max(programmes.base_price - ((discount/100)*programmes.base_price))');

          $query->paginate($limit);
```

[image code]

[image]

I've made a raw query like this:

[raw code]

```
SELECT `timeslots`.*, 
       ( discount / 100 ) * programmes.base_price 
       AS discounted_price, 
       ( programmes.base_price - 
       ( ( discount / 100 ) * programmes.base_price ) ) AS 
       price 
FROM   `timeslots` 
       INNER JOIN `programmes` 
               ON `timeslots`.`programme_id` = `programmes`.`id` 
WHERE  `start_time` > '2015-11-10 00:00:00' 
       AND `end_time` < '2015-11-10 23:59:59' 
       AND `inventory` > 0 
       AND (SELECT Count(*) 
            FROM   `timeslot_properties` 
                   INNER JOIN `timeslot_property_timeslot_map` 
                           ON `timeslot_properties`.`id` = 
`timeslot_property_timeslot_map`.`timeslot_property_id` 
WHERE  `timeslot_property_timeslot_map`.`timeslot_id` = `timeslots`.`id` 
AND `timeslot_property_id` = 1) >= 1 
AND (SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   `programmes` 
WHERE  `timeslots`.`programme_id` = `programmes`.`id` 
AND `owner_id` = 2 
AND `owner_type` = 'Activity' 
AND (SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   `listings` 
WHERE  `programmes`.`listing_id` = `listings`.`id` 
 AND `is_approved` = 1 
 AND `is_bookable` = 1 
 AND (SELECT Count(*) 
      FROM   `locations` 
      WHERE  `listings`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id` 
             AND `id` = 3) >= 1) >= 1) >= 1 
GROUP  BY `programmes`.`listing_id` 
HAVING Max(price)
```

[image code]

[image]

I'm not getting the desired result! :(
Can you please help me!

---

By - 'not getting desired result' I mean that -
I'm getting result as -

```
"timeslots": [
      {
        "id": 127,
        "programme_id": 2,
        "start_time": "2015-11-10 06:00:00",
        "end_time": "2015-11-10 06:30:00",
        "discount": 25,
        "inventory": 200,
        "created_at": "2015-10-19 16:52:18",
        "updated_at": "2015-10-20 16:26:17",
        "discounted_price": "375.0000",
        "price": "1125.0000",
        "programme": {
          "id": 2,
          "listing_id": 30,
          "base_price": 1500,
          "owner_id": 2,
          "owner_type": "Activity",
          "is_activated": 1,
          "created_at": "2015-10-12 15:13:55",
          "updated_at": "2015-10-19 10:45:48",
          "listing": {
            "id": 30,
            "client_id": 42,
            "name": "Listing Name 1",
            "location_id": 3,
            "is_approved": 1,
            "is_bookable": 1,
            "created_at": "2015-10-12 15:13:55",
            "updated_at": "2015-10-28 23:37:20"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 134,
        "programme_id": 2,
        "start_time": "2015-11-10 06:00:00",
        "end_time": "2015-11-10 06:30:00",
        "discount": 25,
        "inventory": 200,
        "created_at": "2015-10-19 16:52:18",
        "updated_at": "2015-10-20 16:26:17",
        "discounted_price": "700.0000",
        "price": "1400.0000",
        "programme": {
          "id": 2,
          "listing_id": 30,
          "base_price": 1500,
          "owner_id": 2,
          "owner_type": "Activity",
          "is_activated": 1,
          "created_at": "2015-10-12 15:13:55",
          "updated_at": "2015-10-19 10:45:48",
          "listing": {
            "id": 30,
            "client_id": 42,
            "name": "Listing Name 1",
            "location_id": 3,
            "is_approved": 1,
            "is_bookable": 1,
            "created_at": "2015-10-12 15:13:55",
            "updated_at": "2015-10-28 23:37:20"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

In the above result, I am getting listing as same for both (listing id: 30 in timeslots_id: 127, 134). I want that the query should give those results by grouping listings on the basis of minimum price attribute inside timeslots array.!!

Comment: I do not have an answer, but can you please elaborate on what you mean by "not getting the desired result!"? What is the actual result, and how does it differ from what you expected?  As an aside, it is preferable to post code/sql as text (not as image).

Comment: Let me elaborate it..... I'll update my question in a while!!